# show that $f(x)= \frac{\exp(-\frac{x-u}{\sigma})}{\sigma(1+\exp(-\frac{x-u}{\sigma}))^2}$ is dominated by a Laplace distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

show that:

$$f(x)= \frac{\exp(-\frac{x-u}{\sigma})}{\sigma(1+\exp(-\frac{x-u}{\sigma}))^2}$$

is dominated by a double expoential (Laplace) distribution after proper scaling.

What is it meant by proper scaling and how do you show a density is being dominated? How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Guess: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling Similar to the envelope distribution in rejection sampling, you need to find a finite constant $M$ such that $Mg(x) \geq f(x)$ for all real-valued $x$, where $g$ is the pdf of Laplace distribution. So this will be just a calculus exercise. The relation holds because the tail of Laplace is relatively  fatter.

Comment: how would I show $Mg(x) \geq f(x)$ ? that seems very difficult @BGM

Comment: In other word you need to study the function $f(x)/g(x)$ and see if it has a global maximum $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your density of interest and the Laplace are symmetric, around their respective means $\mu$, so it makes sense to start off taking the dominating Laplace to have the same mean.

To check that $f(x)$ is indeed symmetric around $\mu$ we have
$$
\begin{align}
f(\mu - y) &= \frac{e^{\frac{y}{\sigma}}}{\sigma(1+e^{\frac{y}{\sigma}})^2} \\
&= \frac{e^{\frac{y}{\sigma}}}{\sigma(e^{\frac{y}{\sigma}}e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}} + e^{2\frac{y}{\sigma}}e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}} )^2} \\
&= \frac{e^{\frac{y}{\sigma}}}{\sigma(e^{2\frac{y}{\sigma}}(e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}} + e^{\frac{y}{\sigma}}e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}})^2)} \\
&= \frac{e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}}}{\sigma(1 + e^{-\frac{y}{\sigma}})^2} = f(\mu + y).
\end{align} 
$$

Now Since these distributions are symmetric around $\mu$ and they are absolutely continuous with respect to each other so that we can take the ratio $g(x)/f(x)$ then the problem becomes; find $M$ such that
$$
M \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \geq 1, \qquad x \geq \mu.
$$
Letting the Laplace have density
$$
g(x) = \frac{1}{2b}e^{-\frac{|x - \mu|}{b}},
$$
then we find easily that
$$
\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{\sigma (1 + e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}})^2}{2b}\cdot \exp\left\{ - \frac{|x-\mu|}{b} + \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right\}, \qquad x \geq \mu,
$$
this is easily simplified taking the dominating Laplace to have $b = \sigma$, giving
\begin{align}
\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} &= \frac{1}{2} (1 + e^{-\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}})^2 \\
&\geq \frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}
And therefore 
$$
2 \cdot g(x)\geq f(x).
$$

[image]

Comment: If I were using rejection sampling to generate random numbers from $f(x)$ would I choose $g(x)$ as my proposal distribution and take $C=2$ ?

Comment: Yeah so you would sample from the Laplace distribution with the same mean and standard deviation then accept the points with propbability $\frac{f(x)}{2g(x)}$, in particular out in the tails you will almost always be accepting, while around the mean the disparity between the two is greater. The Wikipedia page for rejection sampling has a good explanation of this.